# How to use formatted message in Log4j2 with slf4j

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, log4j2

Is it possible to format a log message with the syntax from `String.format` when Log4j2 is used behind slf4j?

It seems the standard `MessageFactory` is `ParameterizedMessageFactory` which supports only `{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the MessageFactory on a per Logger basis as you can with the Log4j API. However, you can change the default MessageFactory by setting log4j2.messageFactory to the MessageFactory class name you want to use.  You can either specify it as a system property or you can define the property in a file named log4j2.component.properties that can be found in the classpath.

I would suggest you might want to consider using the FormattedMessageFactory as it supports String.format patterns, MessageFormat patterns and ParameterizedMessage patterns (not in the same message though).

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't able to figure this out myself because I use Log4j 2.5 and this feature was added in 2.6 (which has not been released at this point). This is the related issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1284 Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that without accessing the native logger, but that would be messy and not very useful, in the end. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831785/slf4j-log-level-as-an-argument) if you really want to do that.