# SLF4J - simplelogger.properties ignored

Tags: java, spring-boot, slf4j, lombok

I am trying to use `simplelogger.properties` for my Java Spring project.
Additionally I want to use Lombok `@Slf4j` annotation.

Unfortunately my `simplelogger.properties` is ignored.
Changes in the logging level done there do not show any effect.

My `pom.xml` dependencies look like:

```
        <!-- SPRING -->
        ...

        <!-- LOMBOK -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.10</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SLF4J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.28</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

What my `simplelogger.properties` looks like:

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=debug
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=false
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showThreadName=false
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showLogName=false
```

What a usage of the logger would look like:

```
@Slf4j
public class Frankenstein {
    public Frankenstein() {
        log.debug("i am alive");
    }
}
```

I am not able to view the debug message by setting the logging level to debug within the `simplelogger.properties`.

I would like to use the `simplelogger.properties` to change the logging level.

Comment: I guess that this is not related to Lombok.`@SLF4J` only creates the logger field.

Comment: Old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442967/how-to-dynamically-change-log-level-in-slf4j-or-log4j) - but with recent updates, and may be worth a look? Especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57572183/12567365)?

Comment: Yup. It seems to be ignored. Has anyone filed a defect fore this yet?

Comment: I take it back. It seems to work form me in the lastest 1.7.x version.

Comment: I am no longer working on the project. Therefore I con give no update if the new version solves the problem for me too.
Nevertheless, it is nice to see that it is working for for you with version 1.7.x