# How do you dynamically pick a logging level for your messages when using SLF4J?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

How do you dynamically pick a log message level when using SLF4J? Is it possible? I would like to avoid writing code like

```java
String message = "message";
if (someCondition) {
    log.info(message);
} else if (someOtherCondition) {
    log.warn(message);
} // and potentially even more ifs
```

This would be better (the code is made-up, such methods don't actually exist)

```java
String message = "message";
log.log(message, levelProvider::getLoggingLevel);
```

Please note this question is not about [setting a logging level of the entire logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442967/how-to-dynamically-change-log-level-in-slf4j-or-log4j)

Comment: It's a strange use case. Usually when the condition makes a higher log level necessary, you would also want to change the message. It's a different thing that happens, after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to use [`Logger.atLevel(Level)`](https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html#atLevel-org.slf4j.event.Level-) to get a [`LoggingEventBuilder`](https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/spi/LoggingEventBuilder.html). You can then call [`log(String)`](https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/spi/LoggingEventBuilder.html#log-java.lang.String-) on that. Like,

```
logger.atLevel(levelProvider.getLoggingLevel()).log(message);
```